Inject Office.js api in browser extension (Chrome/edge/mozilla)
I am trying to inject office.js in my chrome extension but I found that in manifest version 3 we can not inject any external js but instead of this we may need to host or copy the js in extension folder and serve it from inside content script.
I tried the same thing but it is not working, getting lots of errors. Do anyone have any sort of information how we can use office.js functionality inside browser extensions?
My main task is to select the text and replace the text on online office word/powerpoint
